# Is it possible that Android wouldn't call the constructor of my custom Application class?

Tags: android

My custom `Application` class initializes some fields. There isn't any fancy logic to it, it is literally just assigning values.

This works for the majority of users, like in the millions. But if I go to the crash reports on the Play Store console I can see that the `onCreate` of my main `Activity` is trying to access one of those values and failing with `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException`. There aren't many reports, like ~100 users vs the millions that have used that version of the app.

My first thought was that these were users trying to crack my premium version, since one common thing they do is replace the `Application` class, but then I selected on the Play Store the filter that says installed from Google Play. The number of crashes dropped but it is still listed there.

So either my constructor is not getting called. Or the `onCreate` on my main `Activity` is getting called before, both of which sound impossible.

This is what my code looks like:

```
class MyApp: Application() {


    init{
        someVal = "someVal"
    }

    
    companion object{
        lateinit var someVal:String
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         //this is where the exception kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException happens.
         val someVal = MyApp.someVal
    }
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how this can be happening?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ov18d2/this_is_why_your_subclassed_application_isnt/

In a nutshell, if you allow for backups (`android:allowBackup="true"`), when the backup runs, your process is forked but your custom `Application` is not used. That shouldn't affect an activity — I sincerely hope that Android gives you a properly-created process for those — but it might affect other logic that you have that could run inside the backup process.

Comment: interesting post overall, do you think there's still a place in modern android development to actually be making use of an application class, or is this slowly heading towards an anti pattern

Comment: @a_local_nobody: For bootstrapping initialization of your dependency inversion framework, a custom `Application` seems unavoidable. However, I would try to minimize what's there and try to leverage DI more. And, if you are going to allow backups, be careful about what you try doing from the backup process -- if needed, confirm that the `Application` instance really is your subclass before making assumptions about what it might have done.

Comment: Interesting, my crash is at the `Activity.onCreate()` when it tries to access that value, so basically the suggestion on that post is that the backup happens and then the next time the user uses the app, the `Application` class isn't instantiated? I really don't wanna disable backup if possible, but that sounds like an awful side effect.

Comment: @casolorz: It's possible that somehow something else is going on for your case. I was hoping perhaps that I misread your question and that the crash was maybe happening somewhere else. I *sincerely* hope that Android only uses the backup process for the act of backing things up and forks a fresh process for "real" app use. I don't know off the top of my head if there is a good way to determine that your process was created for a backup.

Comment: While looking at how some "cracked" apks work, replacing the `Application` class is pretty common, but the filter for `installed from Google Play` makes me think that isn't the issue here. I guess I can hope that the filter on the Play Store Console isn't perfect.